# Prove that $\dfrac{\sigma_1(n)}{n} = \sigma_{-1}(n)$ where $\sigma_x(n)$ is the sum of the $x$th powers of the positive divisors of $n$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, alternative-proof, divisor-sum

I computed $\dfrac{\sigma_1(n)}{n}$ and $\sigma_{-1}(n)$ on a good hundred values of $n$, and they seem to always match.

For example:

$\dfrac{\sigma_1(6)}{6} = \dfrac{1 + 2 + 3 + 6}{6} = \dfrac{12}{6} = 2$

$\sigma_{-1}(6) = \dfrac{1}{1} + \dfrac{1}{2} + \dfrac{1}{3} + \dfrac{1}{6} = \dfrac{6}{6} + \dfrac{3}{6} + \dfrac{2}{6} + \dfrac{1}{6} = \dfrac{12}{6} = 2$

Humm... Now that I'm actually writing all of this down, I think I have an idea how to prove this...

For every positive integer $n$, all the $m$ divisors of $n$ can be grouped into $\dfrac{m}{2}$ pairs {$d_k$ ; $d_{m+1-k}$} such that $d_k \times d_{m+1-k} = n$ with $1 \leq k \leq m$

$d_k = \dfrac{n}{d_{m+1-k}}$

$\dfrac{\sigma_1(n)}{n} = \dfrac{d_1}{n} + \dfrac{d_2}{n} + \dfrac{d_3}{n} +$ $... + \dfrac{d_{m-2}}{n} + \dfrac{d_{m-1}}{n} + \dfrac{d_m}{n} $

$\sigma_{-1}(n) = \dfrac{1}{d_1} + \dfrac{1}{d_2} + \dfrac{1}{d_3} +$ $... + \dfrac{1}{d_{m-2}} + \dfrac{1}{d_{m-1}} + \dfrac{1}{d_m} + $

$\sigma_{-1}(n) = \dfrac{d_m}{n} + \dfrac{d_{m-1}}{n} + \dfrac{d_{m-2}}{n} +$ $... + \dfrac{d_3}{n} + \dfrac{d_2}{n} + \dfrac{d_1}{n}$

$\sigma_{-1}(n) = \dfrac{\sigma_1(n)}{n}$

And voila!

I'm not totally sure it's perfectly rigorous but it seems to be correct.

If $n$ is a square there's $d_{\frac{m+1}{2}}$ that isn't in a pair but we have: $d_{\frac{m+1}{2}}^2 = n$ so $d_{\frac{m+1}{2}} = \dfrac{n}{d_{\frac{m+1}{2}}}$

Well, how about you try to find some different proofs for my equality then? Maybe someone can find an even simpler and more elegant proof.

.

Hallowed is 120.

$\dfrac{\sigma_1(120)}{120} = \dfrac{360}{120} = 3$

$\sigma_{-1}(120) = 3$

Comment: Seems fine to me. The main point is that the divisors of $n$ occur in pairs $d$ and $n/d$.

Comment: Such things were used by Ramanujan in 1915, but printed only much later. See Srinivasa Ramanujan, annotated by Jean-Louis Nicolas and Guy Robin. Highly composite numbers, The Ramanujan Journal, 1, 1997, 119--153. ramanujanNR.pdf   which is item number 56 at http://math.univ-lyon1.fr/homes-www/nicolas/publications.html

Comment: His survey on highly composite numbers, which gives a good feel for the basic construction is  Jean-Louis Nicolas. On highly composite numbers, In Ramanujan Revisited, Proceedings of the Centenary Conference, University of Illinois at Urbana-Champaign, 1987, éditeurs G.E. Andrews, R.A. Askey, B.C. Berndt, K.G. Ramanathan, R.A. Rankin, hcnrevisited.pdf   Item 77.  Meanwhile, Alaoglu and Erdos, about 1944, is available elsewhere on the web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sigma_k(p^a)=\dfrac{1-p^{k(a+1)}}{1-p^k}=p^{ka}\dfrac{p^{-k(a+1)}-1}{p^{-k}-1}=p^{ka}\sigma_{-k}(p^a)$